# Undefined reference during compilation when providing full header path using Makefile for Contiki

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, include, contiki

Thank in advance for the help.

I am trying to compile an example contiki program (that I wrote, it's not from the examples provided from the contiki git) running a tsch mac.  Below is the code I would like to compile (What it does isn't that important, all I want to do is send a message every second or so and see if I can receive it using tsch; also I know that there is some dead code, I intend to change this in the future).

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "contiki-net.h"

// ATTEMPT TO FIX MY PROBLEM
#include "/home/user/contiki-master/core/net/mac/tsch/tsch.h"
// WHAT CODE SHOULD BE
// #include "net/mac/tsch/tsch.h"

/*
 * Header containing code to use LEDs
 */ 
#include "dev/leds.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG DEBUG_PRINT
#include "net/ip/uip-debug.h"

// header file for this specific example, contains constants
#include "./example-tsch-common.h"

#define UIP_IP_BUF   ((struct uip_udpip_hdr *)&uip_buf[UIP_LLH_LEN])

static struct etimer tsch_example_etimer_struct_timer;

PROCESS(coord_process, "TSCH Coordinator");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&coord_process);

PROCESS_THREAD(coord_process, ev, data)
{
    static uip_ds6_addr_t *myaddr;
    static uip_ipaddr_t ipaddr;
    static uip_ipaddr_t linklocal_all_node;
    static struct uip_udp_conn *conn_unicast;
    static struct uip_udp_conn *conn_broadcast;
    static int unicast_received = 0;
    static int broadcast_received = 0;

    linkaddr_t *dest_lladdr;

    PROCESS_BEGIN();

    uiplib_ip6addrconv(NODE_ADDR, &ipaddr);
    conn_unicast = udp_new(&ipaddr, UIP_HTONS(APP_PORT), NULL);
    uip_udp_bind(conn_unicast, UIP_HTONS(APP_PORT));

    myaddr = uip_ds6_get_link_local(-1);

    tsch_set_coordinator(1);

    while(1) {
        PROCESS_YIELD();
        etimer_set(&tsch_example_etimer_struct_timer, CLOCK_SECOND);
        PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(ev == PROCESS_EVENT_TIMER);
        printf("COORD TX\n");
        uip_udp_packet_send(conn_unicast, uip_appdata, uip_datalen());
    }


    PRINTF("APP: done\n");
    PROCESS_END();
}
```

Whenever I attempt to compile though

```
make TARGET=sky example-tsch-coord
```

I get the following error

```
example-tsch-coord.co: In function `process_thread_coord_process':
/home/user/contikiProgramSourceFiles/tschTest1/example-tsch- 
coord.c:145: undefined reference to `tsch_set_coordinator'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [example-tsch-coord.sky] Error 1
rm example-tsch-coord.co obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o
```

Here is the Makefile I am using ("/home/user/contikiProgramSourceFiles/tschTest1" is where the code I want to compile is)

```
CONTIKI = /home/user/contiki-master
CONTIKI_WITH_IPV6 = 1

MODULES += $(CONTIKI)/core/net/mac/tsch
MODULES += /home/user/contikiProgramSourceFiles/tschTest1

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

The problem (at least I'm pretty sure) is that the compiler can't find the function "tsch_set_coordinator" which is defined in

```
/home/user/contiki-master/core/net/mac/tsch/tsch.h
```

My initial thought was that I was doing something wrong with my makefile since I essentially copied it from the make file in

```
/home/user/contiki-master/examples/ipv6/rpl-tsch/Makefile
```

So what I did was provide that absolute path to the needed header within the actual code (provided above and marked with "ATTEMPT TO FIX MY PROBLEM").  This however did not fix the problem.  My understand is that since I have provided the entire path the compiler should have been able to find the function it can't seem to find.  What am I doing wrong here?

Also, here is the project-conf.h file that I am using in case there is something that I'm leaving out that would cause this problem

```
#undef UIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL
#define UIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL 0

#define TSCH_SCHEDULE_CONF_WITH_6TISCH_MINIMAL 1

/* Netstack layers */
#undef NETSTACK_CONF_MAC
#define NETSTACK_CONF_MAC     tschmac_driver
#undef NETSTACK_CONF_RDC
#define NETSTACK_CONF_RDC     nordc_driver
#undef NETSTACK_CONF_FRAMER
#define NETSTACK_CONF_FRAMER  framer_802154

/* IEEE802.15.4 frame version */
#undef FRAME802154_CONF_VERSION
#define FRAME802154_CONF_VERSION FRAME802154_IEEE802154E_2012

/* Need NDP */
#undef UIP_CONF_ND6_SEND_NA
#define UIP_CONF_ND6_SEND_NA         1

#undef UIP_CONF_IPV6_QUEUE_PKT
#define UIP_CONF_IPV6_QUEUE_PKT      1

/* Needed for cc2420 platforms only */
/* Disable DCO calibration (uses timerB) */
#undef DCOSYNCH_CONF_ENABLED
#define DCOSYNCH_CONF_ENABLED 0
/* Enable SFD timestamps (uses timerB) */
#undef CC2420_CONF_SFD_TIMESTAMPS
#define CC2420_CONF_SFD_TIMESTAMPS 1

#undef TSCH_CONF_DEFAULT_TIMESLOT_LENGTH
#define TSCH_CONF_DEFAULT_TIMESLOT_LENGTH 10000
```

Comment: *"the compiler can't find the function*" - the compiler has nothing to do with this problem. It did its job. It's the *linker* that is puking. An undefined reference is a link-time error, not a compile time error. Mess with the headers all you want, it won't change what you're linking to (MS pragmas for comment-lib notwithstanding) unless you're conditionally *excluding* code from built libraries you later consume by using the preprocessor at compile-time. Judging by your `conf` file, that may be relevant.